# How to convert curl command with -T to axios in node js to upload file to azure datalake

Tags: node.js, axios, azure-data-lake

Requirement : Upload file to azure-datalake directory using axios from nodejs

`curl -i -X PUT -L -T 'C:\temp\list.txt' -H "Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>" 'https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/mytempdir/list.txt?op=CREATE'`

i tried converting  not sure of usage of -T

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Pay attention: this code should be under an `async` function.
If you're executing from node so install: `npm i form-data` and import or require it

```
const url = 'https://<yourstorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/mytempdir/list.txt?op=CREATE';
const headers = {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer <REDACTED>',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

const pathToFile = 'C:\temp\list.txt';

try {
   const formData = createFormData(pathToFile);
   let answer = await axios.put(url, formData, {headers: headers});
   // Handle success...
}
catch(error) {
   console.error(`Problem with posting file...`, error);
   // Handle the error
}


function createFormData(pathToFile) {
    let form = new FormData();
    let bufferedForm = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile);
    form.set('data', bufferedFrom);
    return form;
}
```